# R how to identify duplicate rows in all(multiple columns) and or(multiple columns)?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I want to identify duplicate rows in a data frame based on two types of conditions:

1: `all(multiple columns)`, all the elements in the multiple columns should be the same.

2: `any(multiple columns)`, at least one of the elements in the multiple columns should be the same

3: both 1 and 2 should fit.

```
getRepplicate <- function(df, allCol = "", anyCol = "") {
# both condition 1 and condition 2 are fit, then they are considered as replicated rows
}
```

For example:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3),
  b = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3), 
  d = c("x", "y", "z", "x", "x", "y", "x", "x"),
  e = c("x", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", "z", "x")
)
> df
  a b d e
1 1 1 x x
2 1 2 y y
3 2 2 z z
4 3 3 x x
5 4 4 x x
6 1 1 y x
7 1 1 x z
8 3 3 x x
```

If I apply this function `df2 <- getRepplicate(df, allCol = c("a", "b"), anyCol = c("d", "e"))`, my expected result will be:

```
> df2
  a b d e isReplicate
1 1 1 x x TRUE
2 1 2 y y FALSE
3 2 2 z z FALSE
4 3 3 x x TRUE
5 4 4 x x FALSE
6 1 1 y x TRUE
7 1 1 x z TRUE
8 3 3 x x TRUE
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you mean "entries within a row match": Why are rows 3,4,5,8 false?

Comment: sorry, I did not made myself clear. row 1, 6, 7 are true because in elements in col `a` and `b` are both the same, and at least one element in column `d` and `e` are the same. same applied to rows 4 and 8.

Comment: Well, I have no idea how to reproduce your result. How is row 3 not duplicated as `2=2` and `z=z`?

Comment: I don't want column wise compassion. for instance, row 4 and 8 are considered as replicates, because row 4 and row 8 have the same elements in column a and b `df[4, 1:2] == df[8, 1:2]` & at least one element is the same in `column d and e`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    dupall = duplicated(.) | duplicated(., fromLast = TRUE),
    dup3 = rowSums(sapply(., function(z) duplicated(z) | duplicated(z, fromLast = TRUE))) > 3
  )
#   a b d e dupall  dup3
# 1 1 1 x x  FALSE  TRUE
# 2 1 2 y y  FALSE FALSE
# 3 2 2 z z  FALSE FALSE
# 4 3 3 x x   TRUE  TRUE
# 5 4 4 x x  FALSE FALSE
# 6 1 1 y x  FALSE  TRUE
# 7 1 1 x z  FALSE  TRUE
# 8 3 3 x x   TRUE  TRUE
```

The `dup3` column reflects where 3 or more columns have duplicates. It doesn't indicate which of the columns are dupes.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly tongue in cheek approach with `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% mutate(o = n() > 1) %>% 
  group_by(b) %>% mutate(p = n() > 1) %>% 
  group_by(d) %>% mutate(q = n() > 1) %>% 
  group_by(e) %>% mutate(r = n() > 1) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(isReplicate = all(across(o:r))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-(o:r))
# A tibble: 8 × 5
      a     b d     e     isReplicate
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <lgl>      
1     1     1 x     x     TRUE       
2     1     2 y     y     FALSE      
3     2     2 z     z     FALSE      
4     3     3 x     x     TRUE       
5     4     4 x     x     FALSE      
6     1     1 y     x     TRUE       
7     1     1 x     z     TRUE       
8     3     3 x     x     TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
# Define function
checkRep <- function(df, col_all, col_any) {
  #(1) check input
  if(is.null(col_all) & is.null(col_any))stop("At least one column should be selected.")
  
  #(2) check condition 1.
  if(is.null(col_all)){
    df$allReplicate = TRUE
    } else{
      df <- df %>% 
        group_by(across(col_all)) %>%
        mutate(allReplicate = n() > 1) %>%
        ungroup()
      }
  
  #(3) check condition 2.
  if(is.null(col_any)){
    Final <- cbind.data.frame(df, anyReplicate = TRUE)
  } else{
    n <- length(col_any)
    m <- dim(df)[1]
    tem <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = n, nrow = m))
    for(i in 1:n)
      tem[, i] <- df %>% 
      group_by(!!sym(col_any[i])) %>%
      mutate(x = n() > 1) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      select(x)
    tem2 <- tem %>%
      rowwise() %>% 
      mutate(anyReplicate = any(colSums(.) > 0)) %>%
      select(anyReplicate)
    Final <- cbind.data.frame(df, tem2)
    }
  
  #(4) check both condition 1 & 2.
  Final <- Final %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(isReplicate = ifelse(isTRUE(allReplicate) & isTRUE(anyReplicate), TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
    select(-c(allReplicate, anyReplicate)) %>%
    relocate(isReplicate)
  return(Final)
}

# Check the result
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3),
  b = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3), 
  d = c("x", "y", "z", "x", "x", "y", "x", "x"),
  e = c("x", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", "z", "x")
)

col_all <- c("a", "b")
col_any <- c("d", "e")
checkRep(df, col_all, col_any)
```